# SQL - MULTI-PART IDENTIFIER ERROR: The multi-part identifier "OBDATE.SUMMARY_BLOCK_ID" could not be bound

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, subquery

Not sure why I'm getting the following error...
The multi-part identifier "OBDATE.SUMMARY_BLOCK_ID" could not be bound.

Here is my join statement...

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT SUMMARY_BLOCK_ID
            ,max(ob_dt_eddsys_dt) as [DUE_DATE]                             
     from HSB_DATING AS OBDATE
     GROUP BY SUMMARY_BLOCK_ID) AS [LATEST_DUE_DATE]
ON OBHSBV.SUMMARY_BLOCK_ID = OBDATE.SUMMARY_BLOCK_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this part of the query:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
    SELECT SUMMARY_BLOCK_ID , max(ob_dt_eddsys_dt) as [DUE_DATE]
    FROM HSB_DATING AS OBDATE
    GROUP BY SUMMARY_BLOCK_ID
) AS [LATEST_DUE_DATE]
    ON OBHSBV.SUMMARY_BLOCK_ID = OBDATE.SUMMARY_BLOCK_ID
```

`OBDATE` is not available in the outer query. You aliased this derived table `[LATEST_DUE_DATE]`, so you should use that to refer to it:

```
ON OBHSBV.SUMMARY_BLOCK_ID = [LATEST_DUE_DATE].SUMMARY_BLOCK_ID
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes because that slip right over my head (I should have known that) or maybe I need another cup of coffee...lol. Thanks so much!!